# Submit data via web form and extract the results

Tags: python, web-crawler, web-scraping

My python level is Novice. I have never written a web scraper or crawler. I have written a python code to connect to an api and extract the data that I want. But for some the extracted data I want to get the gender of the author. I found this web site `http://bookblog.net/gender/genie.php` but downside is there isn't an api available. I was wondering how to write a python to submit data to the form in the page and extract the return data. It would be a great help if I could get some guidance on this.

This is the form dom:

```
<form action="analysis.php" method="POST">
<textarea cols="75" rows="13" name="text"></textarea>
<div class="copyright">(NOTE: The genie works best on texts of more than 500 words.)</div>
<p>
<b>Genre:</b>
<input type="radio" value="fiction" name="genre">
fiction&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" value="nonfiction" name="genre">
nonfiction&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" value="blog" name="genre">
blog entry
</p>
<p>
</form>
```

results page dom:

```
<p>
<b>The Gender Genie thinks the author of this passage is:</b>
male!
</p>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No need to use mechanize, just send the correct form data in a POST request.

Also, using regular expression to parse HTML is a bad idea. You would be better off using a HTML parser like lxml.html.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh


def gender_genie(text, genre):
    url = 'http://bookblog.net/gender/analysis.php'
    caption = 'The Gender Genie thinks the author of this passage is:'

    form_data = {
        'text': text,
        'genre': genre,
        'submit': 'submit',
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data)

    tree = lh.document_fromstring(response.content)

    return tree.xpath("//b[text()=$caption]", caption=caption)[0].tail.strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print gender_genie('I have a beard!', 'blog')
```

Comment: i tried to do easy_install lxml.html but getting the following error easy_install lxml.html
Searching for lxml.html
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml.html/
Couldn't find index page for 'lxml.html' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for lxml.html
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('lxml.html')

Comment: In a module import, if two names have a `.` between them, it means that the second name is within the previous name. The module you want to install is lxml.

Comment: thanks I realized it after putting the comment. Thanks agianl

Comment: What is the method was `POST`?

Answer (score 17):

You can use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to submit and retrieve content, and the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module for getting what you want. For example, the script below does it for the text of your own question:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

text = """
My python level is Novice. I have never written a web scraper 
or crawler. I have written a python code to connect to an api and 
extract the data that I want. But for some the extracted data I want to 
get the gender of the author. I found this web site 
http://bookblog.net/gender/genie.php but downside is there isn't an api 
available. I was wondering how to write a python to submit data to the 
form in the page and extract the return data. It would be a great help 
if I could get some guidance on this."""

browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://bookblog.net/gender/genie.php")

browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['text'] = text
browser['genre'] = ['nonfiction']

response = browser.submit()

content = response.read()

result = re.findall(
    r'<b>The Gender Genie thinks the author of this passage is:</b> (\w*)!', content)

print result[0]
```

What does it do? It creates a `mechanize.Browser` and goes to the given URL:

```
browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://bookblog.net/gender/genie.php")
```

Then it selects the form (since there is only one form to be filled, it will be the first):

```
browser.select_form(nr=0)
```

Also, it sets the entries of the form...

```
browser['text'] = text
browser['genre'] = ['nonfiction']
```

... and submit it:

```
response = browser.submit()
```

Now, we get the result:

```
content = response.read()
```

We know that the result is in the form:

```
<b>The Gender Genie thinks the author of this passage is:</b> male!
```

So we create a regex for matching and use `re.findall()`:

```
result = re.findall(
    r'<b>The Gender Genie thinks the author of this passage is:</b> (\w*)!',
    content)
```

Now the result is available for your use:

```
print result[0]
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is a fantastic answer for a new b like me great explanation. Wish I can upvote more than once.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), see [examples](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) for details.

```
from mechanize import ParseResponse, urlopen, urljoin

uri = "http://bookblog.net"

response = urlopen(urljoin(uri, "/gender/genie.php"))
forms = ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
form = forms[0]

#print form

form['text'] = 'cheese'
form['genre'] = ['fiction']

print urlopen(form.click()).read()
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. sounds like machanize is a module I have install? quickly tested on the terminal got the no module error. I am not a mac, should I be able to do easy_install to get machanize.

Comment: Oh, right, it's an external module. Yes, you can do easy_install mechanize.