# inputting into a web form Python

Tags: python

I'm accessing HTML on a web page and submitting some input into the form. I followed this page
[Submit data via web form and extract the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377055/submit-data-via-web-form-and-extract-the-results) step by step and it works with the site he used on post 3. I'm using all the values are right.

The error I'm getting is this and don't know why it works with the other site and not the one intended.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: unknown GET form encoding type 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before you call submit() `browser.form.enctype = ""`

Comment: thanks for the help now i'm getting this error ValueError: unknown GET form encoding type '

Comment: never mind I just had to  put browser.form.enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as a parameter thank u so much god bless you