# Python script to open a website and search in the search box? (not google)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to open dx.doi.org, search for a specific DOI and copy the URL of the result page in an excel sheet to compile the list of links for a database of research papers.

However, as a beginner in python I only know how to do google searches. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and do post what you have attempted to address your needs to get some help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit data via web form and extract the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377055/submit-data-via-web-form-and-extract-the-results)

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377055/submit-data-via-web-form-and-extract-the-results)